# How to show that the limit of sequence of eigenvectors (same eigenvalue) is also an eigenvector?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $H$ be a continuous Hermitian operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Also, let $f_n$ be a sequence approaching $f$ as $n\to\infty$, where each $f_n$ is an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ of H  (i.e. $\forall_n\space Hf_n=\lambda f_n$ ).

Since H is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty} H f_n = H f$. But how can you show from this that $f$ is also an eigenvector ($Hf = \lambda f$)?

Comment: $$Hf = H(\lim f_n) = \lim Hf_n = \lim (\lambda f_n) = \lambda \lim f_n = \lambda f.$$ Alternatively, $H - \lambda I$ is continuous, hence $\ker (H -\lambda I)$ is closed.

Comment: You need $f \neq 0$. If $f_n \to 0$, then it is always true that $\lim Hf_n = \lambda f$.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow Daniel Fischer's second approach: introduce the operator $H-\lambda I$ and observe that its kernel is closed. Note that the Hermitian assumption is not needed.

And the remark by copper.hat should be taken into account: while it's true that the limit will belong to $\ker(H-\lambda I)$, to qualify as an eigenvector, it must be a nonzero vector.